# How to combine two grouped whereIn clauses with Where not in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I tried to use the following mysql clause with Laravel eloquent:

```
SELECT * FROM pages
INNER JOIN page_translations as pt
ON pages.id = pt.page_id
WHERE NOT (page_id IN (93) AND locale IN ('de', 'en'));
```

However, I cannot implement it because of the "WHERE NOT", with the opposite, only using WHERE it is no problem.

So I came that far:

```
Page::join('page_translations as pt', 'pages.id', '=', 'pt.page_id')
            ->where(function($query) use ($homes) {
                $query->whereIn('pages.id', $homes->values()->toArray());
                $query->whereIn('locale', $homes->keys()->toArray());
            })
            ->get();
```

I tried to solve it by using 'whereRaw' or a Raw clause at all, but that didnt really help.

If someone could show me how to bring this SQL query to Laravel Eloquent that would be great.

Comment: Why are you not using relationships ?

Comment: you mean you want to use [`whereNotIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)??

Comment: I need to sort the items that’s why I use a join

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the query using `whereNotIn` as:

```
Page::join('page_translations as pt', 'pages.id', '=', 'pt.page_id')
            ->where(function($query) use ($homes) {
                $query->whereNotIn('pages.id', $homes->values()->toArray());
                $query->whereNotIn('locale', $homes->keys()->toArray());
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but that doesn’t lead to the correct result.

Comment: locale column is in page_translations right?

Comment: I think you have written the wrong SQL statement. Please execute this statement and tell me if you want this result? `SELECT * FROM pages
INNER JOIN page_translations as pt
ON pages.id = pt.page_id and pages.id not in (2) and locale not in ('de', 'en');
`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so while I finally used a different approach on my way I figured out how to  do an eloquent query with the mentioned sql query, so the solution is quite easy actually:

```
Page::join('page_translations as pt', 'pages.id', '=', 'pt.page_id')
        ->whereRaw("not (page_id in (?) and locale in (?)", ,[93], ['de', 'en'])
        ->get();
```